# Always getting Loading commit data github

Tags: git, github

I committed and pushed a folder containing my project files in GitHub. I can see that it has been committed locally (using `git status`) and in the remote too. (commit ids are visible and recent activity timestamps are also changed).

I first committed the files and then committed the folder and pushed the folder to my GitHub repo. I added folders because I want to have different projects which each folder represents one project.

If I see my repo in GitHub, a Loading commit data message is being displayed always in the files Tab and the commit data and files are not visible at all.

What am I missing here? Any pointers regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Updating data might take time (since github probably has replicated data, servers in different places, it's possible it takes minutes to be up-to-date).

Anyway, try again. Also be more explicit, "(commit ids are visible and recent activity timestamps are also changed)." -> on your local copy or on Github? because if it is not on Github it does not help much. Try `git fetch` or `git pull` in your local copy to make sure data is propagated.

You can also make other minor changes and commit/push again, maybe it'll work.

Comment: commit ids are visible and recent activity timestamps are also changed in the GitHub only. It has been displaying the message for days for which I have pushed few files of relatively smaller sizes.

Comment: so try pushing new changes, and see what happens, maybe by doing requests it will "wake up". Also, try to search for the exact error message on Github's site, I think their Help pages are pretty good.